# Remove barrel distortion from an image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have the following fish-eye lens distorted image:

[image]

I've been trying to use the `undistortImage`function for the distortion:

```
image = foam.jpg
cameraParams = cameraParameters('RadialDistortion',[0 0 0]); 
J = undistortImage(image,cameraParams);
```

The problem is that it doesn't recognize the `cameraParameters` function

I am new to image processing, so I don't really know why this error
Anyone has any idea how can I fix it or find an alternative solution?

Comment: yeah, undistort the image. You are not giving any information of what you tried! There is a function to undistort images in matlab with the calibration parameters of the camera, have you looked at that?

Comment: @Bowecho Please edit the question, rather than post code in comments

Comment: You may not have the right toolbox/version for that function.

Comment: Why are you setting your distortion parameters to [0 0 0] ?   Please read the help pages on how to select the barrel/pincushion correction values (and the exact names of the arguments to your functions)

Comment: Plase, read the wikipedia page for camera distortion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics) . You need to understand what the camera parameters are, as setting them to `[0 0 0]` makes no sense. Also, in order to undistort an image, you need a calibration of the camera. If you want to undistort an image by also estimating the camera parameters you are entering a quite complex field of image processing that can only be solved by reading tons of papers. So, or you already have the parameters, our prepare to read a lots of maths!

Comment: I doubt it's about 'lots of maths' (it's a bit vague), but anyway, I wondered if there might be an alternative to what I used. Now I know that what I used is not properly set, and I need to have clear some camera parameters.

Comment: What you used is correct, but you need the camera parameters! you need to calibrate the camera. http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimatecameraparameters.html

Comment: You can't do this without knowing the camera parameters.  The duplicate I've marked should help you.

Comment: Thank you, people. I will check the duplicate out.